# Angular Parent/Children click events: Show child component in parent after click event on a different child in parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-ng-if

I'm a couple weeks into Angular 7 and I'm struggling to hide/show a child component `<app-child-2>` in a Parent component `<parent>` after a click event on a separate child `<app-child-1>` in the same parent component.

All the children card divs **only** render if they have data, this is done via a `ngIf` method from the parent `shouldCardRender()` and `outputsMapToRead('Child 1')`. The `shouldCardRender()` method is used to check if the data object `groupName` is `checked: true` via another method in the parent called `this.checkIfCardHasAnyCheckedValues()` before showing. If false it doesn't render on parent, if true another method runs that feeds all the true data into the child component.

Here's how both children are set in the parent.

```
<div *ngIf="shouldCardRender('Child 1')">
        <app-child-1 [outputsArray]="outputsMapToRead.get('Child 1')" [rawData]="rawData"></app-child-1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="shouldCardRender('Child 2')">
        <app-child-2 [outputsArray]="outputsMapToRead.get('Child 2')" [rawData]="rawData"></app-child-2>
</div>
```

I believe the `[outputsArray]outputsMapToRead.get('Child #')` is the data that categories the groupName for that child and the feeds the true data for the child depending on the groupName.

Here's an example of the data object that `shouldCardRender()` & `this.checkCardValues()` check. If checked is true, card renders. Please note that a normal object, has close to 20 objects inside of it, if those objects are true, a different method gives those cards access to data for the child to plug and play, right now all 'checked` keys are set to **true.**

```
outputsMap.set('Child 1',  [
    {
      name: 'fraudScore',
      friendlyName: 'Fraud Score',
      checked: true, 
      groupName: 'Child 1'
    }, 
    .....
  ]);

outputsMap.set('Child 2',  [
    {
      name: 'displayName',
      friendlyName: 'Display Name',
      checked: true, 
      groupName: 'Child 2'
    }, 
    .....
  ]);
```

My problem is that there is a button on the `<app-child-1>` thats says "Show `<app-child-2>`". 
I am struggling to get `<app-child-2>` to hide/show since that currently depends on the `shouldCardRender` and the data object from `[outputsArray]`.

I believe I have to use `@Output` and `EventEmitter` on child and have it bubble up to the parent. But I'm hitting a road block with the logic needed to turn data to false to hide component. I also thought about changing the checked key to `false` and making method on the child or parent? that turns checked into `true`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So does `app-card-1` == `app-child-1`? or are they different components. If they are the same, do you mind editing your question to remove that difference (confusion)? thanks.

Comment: Anyway, yes you need an @Output decorator. The easiest way to accomplish this would be to set a Boolean member variable on `parent` upon the button click. Then, alter your `*ngIf` to test either data or the Boolean property. Since you are using a method for your `*ngIf` you could handle the testing in that method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn correct, fixed typo!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, before start talking about solution; i wanna describe something important about parent/child components.

- You should use `@Input()` decoration to pass data from *Parent* to *Child*.
- You should use `@Output()` decoration to pass data from *Child* to *Parent*.

You can read more about on [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

- `@Input()` represented in html using **property binding** like:

`<child1 [name]="'testing'"></child1>`

Which means `child1` component has a variable called name that get its value from *parent* component.

- `@Output()` represented in html using **event binding** like:

`<child1 (rebuild)="doSomething($event)"></child1>`

Which means `child1` component has an **EventEmitter** called `rebuild` that returns a value of some type and we catch this value in *parent* component using **$event**.

How can this help you?

I made you an example how to handle your case, check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-interactions).

each child component in this example has a button to show other component, on this button click; child component will pass a `boolean` value that will be catch from *parent* and used in `*ngIf`.

I hope that help you will.